# Incrementing Based on Field

Tags: python, dataset, counting, difference

I have a dataset

```
Sample1    1
Sample1    2
Sample1    3
Sample2    4
Sample2    5
Sample3    6
```

And want it to become

```
Sample1    1
Sample1    2
Sample1    3
Sample2    1
Sample2    2
Sample3    1
```

I've seen numerous posts of how to do this in SQL and other languages, but not python.  Any help would be appreciated (Python 2.5).  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Python libraries have a wonderful utility called itertools. Inside this devil we have two functions called `groupby` and `chain` than can create wonders

Assuming your data set was a string, Let me fetch the first column

```
>>> dataset = zip(*map(str.split, dataset.splitlines()))[0]
```

The grouping is most important. All rows with the same data are grouped together. You only need to suffix it with a counter that you can create by ranging from 1 to the length of each group

```
>>> #Tools of trade, just import them
>>> from itertools import groupby, chain
>>> #Now group your data
>>> grp = [[(key, str(count)) 
             for count in range(1, len(list(grp)) + 1)] 
           for key, grp in groupby(dataset)]
>>> print grp
>>> #You can see how the data is already grouped
>>> [[('Sample1', '1'), ('Sample1', '2'), ('Sample1', '3')], [('Sample2', '1'), ('Sample2', '2')], [('Sample3', '1')]]
```

Finally reformat the data to match your original input dataset

```
>>> #Now recreate your dataset from the grouped data
>>> dataset = '\n'.join('\t'.join(row) for row in chain.from_iterable(grp))
>>> print dataset
```

And here is how your output would look like

```
Sample1 1
Sample1 2
Sample1 3
Sample2 1
Sample2 2
Sample3 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/) to load this txt file in, I added some column names.

```
In [132]:

t="""Sample1    1
Sample1    2
Sample1    3
Sample2    4
Sample2    5
Sample3    6"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), sep='\s+', header=None, names=['Sample', 'Value'])
df
​
Out[132]:
    Sample  Value
0  Sample1      1
1  Sample1      2
2  Sample1      3
3  Sample2      4
4  Sample2      5
5  Sample3      6
```

Once loaded into a dataframe we can perform a [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas.DataFrame.groupby) and then call [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation) on the Value column, we pass a lambda that calls [`rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rank.html#pandas.Series.rank) this will return the ranking of the values using method 'first' for each sample group, transform returns a series that is aligned with the original df:

```
In [133]:

df['Value'] = df.groupby('Sample')['Value'].transform(lambda x: x.rank(method='first'))
df
Out[133]:
    Sample  Value
0  Sample1      1
1  Sample1      2
2  Sample1      3
3  Sample2      1
4  Sample2      2
5  Sample3      1
```